# Minimize and Uglify WordPress Plugin Files

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory, customization

### Intro

When developing a [gulp.js](https://gulpjs.com/) project, it is typical to have the following directory structure

```
PROJECT_NAME
    |
    ---------- dist <------------ contains library to be released
    |
    ---------- src <------------- contains all source code file
```

And the coding flow is

1. Create source files in the `src` directory
2. Once the files in `src` work as designed, the project is "uglified" and "minimized", then copied to the `dist` directory.
3. Once the `dist` directory has the final project, it is released.

So, the released version of the library is taken from the `dist` directory.

### Setup for WordPress

Now, onto WordPress. I typically set my development environment as follows

```
WORDPRESS_ROOT_DIRECTORY
    |
  wp-content
    |
  plugins
    |
  my_plugin
    |
    -------- css  <---------- contains all CSS files
    |
    -------- inc  <---------- contains all PHP files
    |
    -------- js   <---------- contains all JavaScript files
    |
    -------- vendors <------- contains all libraries from other vendors
    |
    -------- my_plugin.php <---- this is the initial plugin file
```

This setup for WordPress would be OK and I have been developing plugins for it without a problem. I would develop, test, and then release.

### The Issue

In my current WordPress project, I am developing a plugin that would require I minimize and uglify every file in the directory (the reasons for that are long, and I am not going into the business cases; it is a requirement). Typically I would like to create the following directory structure.

```
WORDPRESS_ROOT_DIRECTORY
    |
  wp-content
    |
  plugins
    |
  my_plugin
    |
    -------- dist <------ contains all minimized and uglified files
    |
    -------- src
              |
              -------- css  <---------- contains all CSS files
              |
              -------- inc  <---------- contains all PHP files
              |
              -------- js   <---------- contains all JavaScript files
              |
              -------- vendors <------- contains all libraries from other vendors
              |
              -------- my_plugin.php <---- this is the initial plugin file
```

Then, the ideal flow of development would be

1. Develop in the `src` directory
2. Once satified, minimize/uglify all PHP, CSS, and JS files into `dist`
3. Release the plugin from the `dist` directory

I have the following problems

1. I do not know if I can make such setup work. The problem is I will have functions that have the same name (referenced from `my_plugin.php` located in `src` and the minimized 'my_plugin.php' located in `dist`), and this would cause a WordPress function name conflict error.
2. Can I place my root plugin file, `my_plugin.php`, in a sub/sub directory?
3. I am not sure what tools I can use to take my files from `src` and convert them to `dist` while minimizing/uglifying them. I could use gulp.js to do that for my JS and CSS files, but I am not sure about PHP files. I need one tool that does that for all files.

**If I am unable to create the structure above. How can I minimize/uglify ALL my files for my plugin before releasing the plugin? (And by ALL files, I mean PHP, CSS, and JS).**

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but this sound like a software packaging question. as it is right now it is not clear to me which aspects of the question are wordpress specific? If you need just write a more complex build script

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun for your reply. You are right, it is a packaging question, but it is related to WordPress. I am not asking for a script to package. I am asking if it is possible to do so, and what tools to use (either directly within the build, or indirectly outside the build).

Comment: related !== specific. Questions here needs to be specific, otherwise we will end up with questions about how to use phpstorm and other editors.

Comment: I have to disagree with you. The points in the question are specific in its inquiry. Obviously you cannot help in answering it.

Comment: I actually told you what the answer is :(... write better build script

Comment: ... you are basically asking about an advice for writting build scripts from people that are not experts in that

Comment: Mr. Kaplun, thanks for your reply, but I do not think you are even trying to answer the question. You are entitled to your opinions about the answer, and I think it is wrong. You seem to be on a crusade to win arguments rather than actually answer questions, but thanks again.

Comment: hmmm lets see who is answering questions and who is not? how do you think I got my rep exactly? The only one that maintains the argument and being generally impolite in all kind of more or less subtle ways is you. You are welcome to change that attitude when asking your next question

Comment: Totally doable. Take a look at [JointsWP](https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/) (for example), to get yourself started. It's just a matter of writing and configuring the build scripts to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to keep your source in the root of the plugin folder (i.e. your typical WordPress setup listed above). Your build script should write its output to a dist folder at the root of the plugin.

This prevents any possible WordPress conflicts; PHP and WordPress won't parse a file unless it is referenced with an include, require or otherwise in your code. So my_plugin.php in the root of the plugin and in the dist folder won't conflict at all.

Comment: Thanks. What build scripts do you recommend?

Comment: Generally I use grunt. But there any build tool should support this.

Comment: OK, I will try to use gulp. Thanks for your help. You gave me ideas of how to solve this issue.